# How can I change the backcolor of a row in a DevExpress GridView?

Tags: c#, winforms, devexpress

I have a DevExpress GridView in my form and I need to change some rows color due to a boolean value.

What is the property that allows me to change the backcolor of a row ??

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can change the row's color gradient in the `RowStyle` event handler:

```
private void myGridView_RowStyle(object sender,
                       DevExpress.XtraGrid.Views.Grid.RowStyleEventArgs e) 
{
    e.Appearance.BackColor = Color.Green;
    e.Appearance.BackColor2 = Color.LightGreen;
}
```

See: [Customizing Appearances of Individual Rows and Cells](http://documentation.devexpress.com/#WindowsForms/CustomDocument758)

Answer (score 0):

You must handle RowStyle or RowCellStyle event of GridView. Form more detail see http://documentation.devexpress.com/#WindowsForms/DevExpressXtraGridViewsGridGridView_RowCellStyletopic and http://documentation.devexpress.com/#WindowsForms/DevExpressXtraGridViewsGridGridView_RowStyletopic.